Declare dynamic nested object in TypeScript
How to declare this nested dynamic object in TypeScript?
{
  foo: "bar",
  dynamicKey_1: {
    innerKey: "bar",
  },
  dynamicKey_2: {
    innerKey: "bar",
  },
}

Using this doesn't work, I get an error because of foo.
interface NestedObject {
  foo: string;
  [key: string]: {
    innerKey: string;
  };
}

Property 'foo' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type '{ innerKey: string; }'.ts(2411)

Have you checked this? - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-objects-with-dynamic-keys-in-typescript/

Thanks! But this shows the variant without any first level keys like foo. I want to declare some required keys in the first level.

Is there any pattern to the dynamic keys? Or can they be literally any string other than foo?

see prev comment: I assume the dynamic keys are arbitrary strings. If so there is no specific type in TypeScript that works how you want, see ms/TS#17867 for the relevant feature request, and the linked q/a above for more info and various workarounds. If you have some simple pattern to the keys it might be possible; will see if you update. Good luck!

@jcalz thank you so much! https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867 is exactly what I need. Also it's not critical, any would work too. I just wanted to learn it better.

interface NestedObject {
  foo  :string;
  [key: string]: string | {
    foo:string ;
    innerKey: string;
  };
};

try this

This will result in Property 'innerKey' does not exist on type 'string | { name: string; slug: string; }'. Property 'innerKey' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339) - but the initial error is gone.
